# href returning none python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrape

[image: This is the href i am looking for]I am trying to get the href of the first image from google [images](https://www.google.com/search?q=5285000206613&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjzgtKJwZWBAxU8sCcCHfO-DR4Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=5285000206613&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIECCMQJzoHCCMQ6gIQJ1CLCVjdD2DPEmgBcAB4AIABmwKIAZYEkgEDMi0ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWewAQrAAQE&sclient=img&ei=cTD4ZLOGMbzgnsEP8_228AE&bih=905&biw=1745). I don't need the img src but rather the a tag's href. This is my code, it gets the selenium element but the htag is returning none.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys




chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()



driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=5285000201168&sca_esv=560946880&tbm=isch&sxsrf=AB5stBi24FB3-HvM3lZXc7ICrUqeHo3rAQ%3A1693299850492&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=995&ei=irTtZIeVG-PHkdUP96OoiAM&iflsig=AD69kcEAAAAAZO3CmjYgqhpcqRhnPykrz3kO7zPj6_kn&ved=0ahUKEwiHgtbAwYGBAxXjY6QEHfcRCjEQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=5285000201168&gs_lp=EgNpbWciDTUyODUwMDAyMDExNjgyBBAjGCdIwQdQ3wRY3wRwAXgAkAEAmAHBAaABwQGqAQMwLjG4AQPIAQD4AQL4AQGKAgtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ6gCCsICBxAjGOoCGCc&sclient=img")

search_feild = driver.find_element(By.ID,'REsRA')
search_feild.clear()
    # time.sleep(1)
search_feild.send_keys("5285000206613")
search_feild.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


try:
    # Locate the <a> tag element with the specified class attribute using XPath
    link_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class, 'wXeWr') and contains(@class, 'islib') and contains(@class, 'nfEiy')]")

    # Retrieve the href attribute of the <a> tag
    href = link_element.get_attribute("href")

    if href:
        # Print the href attribute
        print("Href:", href)
    else:
        print("Href attribute is empty for the element.")

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I don't see an `href` attribute in the `<a>` node

Comment: check the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause of the issue:** The `href` attribute gets displayed only after you click on the element.

**Solution:** After locating the element, perform a `click()` action on the element and then try to retrieve the `href` value. See below code:

```
# Locate the <a> tag element with the specified class attribute using XPath
link_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[contains(@class, 'wXeWr') and contains(@class, 'islib') and contains(@class, 'nfEiy')]")

# Perform click on the element
link_element.click()

# Retrieve the href attribute of the <a> tag
href = link_element.get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: This works but it returns incorrect href.

Comment: It is getting the second image's href . I am looking for it print the same href from my picture

Comment: @ShotoVenkatesh - Check the updated answer now, I think I know what the issue is. The updated answer should get you the `href` of first image. Try and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get href, because your locator is incorrect.

You are getting image `a` tag, which doesn't have `href` attribute, needed element is next `a` on the same level.

To get it you can use locator below:

```py
link_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role=listitem] a[href]")
href = link_element.get_attribute("href")
```